# I deleted site collection from CA now i want to delete it fast what to do?

Tags: configuration, site-deletion

I deleted a site collection from CA using gradual deletion, but its taking forever.

How can I delete it super fast now ?

This doesn't work https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286317(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Here are the few steps to delete the site collection.

- Delete the Site collections from central admin or powershell
- then remove the deleted site collection using `Remove-SPDeletedSite -Identity`
- Now manually run the **"Gradual Deletion"** timer job from central admin(by default, it runs once a day). Once it completed successfully then site will gone.

Comment: You basically repeated my question, I want something super fast.

Comment: unless, you script all above steps. AFAIK, their is no way to bypass that recyclbin(deletedSites).

Comment: check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2010/05/27/using-powershell-to-delete-a-site-with-subsites-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx